# Re-iterate string extraction for delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Unfortunately I don't have permission to create functions, so I wrote the following query to extract the first, second, third, and fourth parts of pipe delimited `page_name`:

```
select page_name,
LEFT(page_name, first-1) AS P1,
case when second>0 then SUBSTRING(page_name,first+1,second-first-1) 
     else substring(page_name, first+1,1000) end As P2,
case when third>0 then SUBSTRING(page_name,second+1,third-second-1) 
     when second>0 then substring(page_name, second+1,1000) else '' end AS P3,
case when fourth>0 then SUBSTRING(page_name,third+1,fourth-third-1) 
     when third>0 then substring(page_name, third+1,1000) else '' end AS P4

from (
select distinct page_name,
CHARINDEX('|', page_name) first,
CHARINDEX('|', page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name)+1) second,
case when CHARINDEX('|', page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name)+1)=0 then 0 
     else CHARINDEX('|', page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name, charindex('|', page_name)+1)+1) end third,
case when CHARINDEX('|', page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name, charindex('|', page_name)+1)+1)=0 then 0 
     else CHARINDEX('|', page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name, charindex('|', page_name)+1)+1)+1) end fourth
from adobe_analytics
where page_name like '[a-z]%' and page_name like '%|%' 
) a
```

The issue is that sometimes there are close to 10 parts, so I was wondering if there is a better way to write in subquery, which will not force me to reiterate the same type of query formulation in creating the `page_name` parts?

Example data:

```
it-bae|
it-bae|content|advisor in newsletter
it-bae|content|area products|showcase products fideuram|fideuram fonditalia dynamic 
it-bae|content|events|events|events|webinars|new
```

Comment: Get a permission to create functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in advance the maximum number of delimited strings you could have, you could use something along the following lines (it uses a recursive CTE to build up a table of the separate strings, and then pivots them, producing a row for each `page_name` field):

```
-- Table variable is just for example purposes.
DECLARE @tbl table (page_name varchar(255))
;

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
('it-bae|')
, ('it-bae|content|advisor in newsletter')
, ('it-bae|content|area products|showcase products fideuram|fideuram fonditalia dynamic')
, ('it-bae|content|events|events|events|webinars|new')
;

WITH cteParts
AS
(
    SELECT
        page_name
        , 1 single_page_no
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', page_name) = 0 THEN page_name ELSE LEFT(page_name, CHARINDEX('|', page_name) - 1) END single_page_name
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', page_name) > 0 THEN RIGHT(page_name, LEN(page_name) - CHARINDEX('|', page_name)) END remainder
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY page_name) row_id
    FROM @tbl

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        page_name
        , single_page_no + 1
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', remainder) > 0 THEN LEFT(remainder, CHARINDEX('|', remainder) - 1) ELSE remainder END
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', remainder) > 0 THEN RIGHT(remainder, LEN(remainder) - CHARINDEX('|', remainder)) END
        , row_id
    FROM cteParts
    WHERE LEN(remainder) > 0
)

SELECT
    row_id
    , page_name
    , [1]
    , [2]
    , [3]
    , [4]
    , [5]
    , [6]
    , [7]
    , [8]
    , [9]
    , [10]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            row_id
            , page_name
            , single_page_no
            , single_page_name
        FROM cteParts
    ) Q
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(single_page_name)
        FOR single_page_no IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
    ) P
```

Otherwise you would need to use dynamic SQL to achieve something like this.

Here's an example of a dynamic SQL solution:

```
-- Temporary table is just for example purposes.
CREATE TABLE #tbl (page_name varchar(255))
;

INSERT INTO #tbl
VALUES
('it-bae|')
, ('it-bae|content|advisor in newsletter')
, ('it-bae|content|area products|showcase products fideuram|fideuram fonditalia dynamic')
, ('it-bae|content|events|events|events|webinars|new')
;

DECLARE @maxStrings int =
(
    SELECT MAX(LEN(page_name) - LEN(REPLACE(page_name, '|', ''))) + 1
    FROM #tbl
)
;

DECLARE @headers varchar(1000)
;

WITH cteHeaders
AS
(
    SELECT 1 Header
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Header + 1
    FROM cteHeaders
    WHERE Header + 1 <= @maxStrings
)

SELECT DISTINCT @headers = STUFF((SELECT ', [' + CAST(Header AS varchar(3)) + ']' FROM cteHeaders FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM cteHeaders
;

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000) =
'
WITH cteParts
AS
(
    SELECT
        page_name
        , 1 single_page_no
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''|'', page_name) = 0 THEN page_name ELSE LEFT(page_name, CHARINDEX(''|'', page_name) - 1) END single_page_name
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''|'', page_name) > 0 THEN RIGHT(page_name, LEN(page_name) - CHARINDEX(''|'', page_name)) END remainder
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY page_name) row_id
    FROM #tbl

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        page_name
        , single_page_no + 1
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''|'', remainder) > 0 THEN LEFT(remainder, CHARINDEX(''|'', remainder) - 1) ELSE remainder END
        , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''|'', remainder) > 0 THEN RIGHT(remainder, LEN(remainder) - CHARINDEX(''|'', remainder)) END
        , row_id
    FROM cteParts
    WHERE LEN(remainder) > 0
)

SELECT
    row_id
    , page_name
    , ' + @headers + '
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            row_id
            , page_name
            , single_page_no
            , single_page_name
        FROM cteParts
    ) Q
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(single_page_name)
        FOR single_page_no IN (' + @headers + ')
    ) P
'

EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE #tbl
```

Comment: I made a few important edits since you accepted the answer!

Comment: Thank you this is great!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need your values in columns or in rows. It would make more sense in rows if the number of values is unknown. This can be achieved with an xml splitter.

```
SELECT page_name,
    Value
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY( SELECT cast(('<X>' + replace( page_name, '|' ,'</X><X>') + '</X>') as xml) AS xmlpage_name) AS x
CROSS APPLY( SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(255)') as value FROM xmlpage_name.nodes('X') as T(N)) AS Split;
```

If you need to show the values in columns, you should probably have a defined number of columns to keep the values.

```
SELECT page_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 1 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 2 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 3 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 4 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 5 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 6 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 7 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P7,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 8 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P8,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 9 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P9,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ItemNumber = 10 THEN Value ELSE '' END) AS P10
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY( SELECT cast(('<X>' + replace( page_name, '|' ,'</X><X>') + '</X>') as xml) AS xmlpage_name) AS x
CROSS APPLY( SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(255)') as value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ItemNumber FROM xmlpage_name.nodes('X') as T(N)) AS Split
GROUP BY page_name;
```